# Javascript get image source and inject into another image source

Tags: javascript, html, image

I've been working on a Javascript photo gallery and I want it to be very user-friendly. This involves only having to use one image and one link per image. I have it so all the images appear in a scrolling div on the left and onClick it is suppose to change the image source on the right but I can't seem to get javascript to get the image source from the original image and change the second one with it. I've tried a few other ways but this is the way I like and if I could get it to work it would be perfect.

This is inside a table so it is align differently I'm just giving the code needed.

This code was given below but it seems as though he deleted his answer. I think you were much close than me!

Javascript:

```
<script type="Text/javscript">

function setImage(this) {
    document.getElementById("ImageFrame").src = this.childNodes[0].src;
}

</script>
```

break

```
    <div style="width:275;height:400;overflow-x:scroll;">

     <a href="#" onclick="setImage(this);"><img class="gallery" src="JCF/PICT0421.jpg" /></a>

     <a href="#" onclick="setImage(this);"><img class="gallery" src="JCF/PICT0422.jpg" /></a>

     <a href="#" onclick="setImage(this);"><img class="gallery" src="JCF/PICT0423.jpg" /></a>

</div>
```

The image being changed.

```
    <div>
<img id="ImageFrame" src="JCF/PICT0421.jpg" width="400" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working example. `NOTE: a.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src` as different browsers would add nodes to  tag before and after the child  tag. `It is safe to use getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src`

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setImg(a){
          //alert(a.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src);
              document.getElementById('ImageFrame').src = 
                          a.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="setImg(this);"><img src="JCF/PICT0421.jpg"></a>

        <div>
           <img id="ImageFrame" src="JCF/PICT0421.jpg" width="400" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uncomment the alert and check the message. It should show the correct img source for you. This works fine for me. `Do not use obj.childNode[0] as 0th node will not be always an img tag. It depends on the browser.`

Comment: Ok this must seriously be me because even the javascript alert isn't working for me and I know I have this in correctly.

Comment: Copy this full answer to your notepad, change the img.src to an existing filename then save as html file. See if it works that way. Also note my function name is `SetImg()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var pic1 = document.getElementById("image1"); 
var src = pic1.src;  // here is the src for image1

var pic2 = document.getElementById("image2"); 
pic1.src = src;  // here we set the src for image2
```

So this code will take the image `src` from image1 and put it in image2.

Comment: I know how to do this this is what most people would do, in mine im trying to go for simplicity where you don't have to make separate functions, there is just one universal code in each onClick.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this should work for you:

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" onclick="setImage(this);"><img class="gallery" id="image1" src="image1.jpg" /></a>
```

**Javascript**:

```
function setImage(imgParent) {
    document.getElementById("ImageFrame").src = imgParent.childNodes[0].src;
}​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rDt7P/3/)

The Demo will work better when you actually load in images. However, if you inspect the broken images, you can see that it is loading in the new image correctly.

**Edit**:

Since Kaf mentioned that he has had issues with childNodes, you may want to try this out instead:

**Javascript**:

```
function setImage(imgParent) {
    document.getElementById("ImageFrame").src = imgParent.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
}​
```

Comment: Remove the this and replace it with something else such as imgParent in my case. Otherwise it throws a javascript error. I thought it would work with this but I was wrong. That is why I removed my answer initially. :P

Comment: The live demo doesn't seem to work either. I checked the source of the code and the image didn't change.

Comment: Ooops I linked in the wrong demo. It is fixed now. The code posted above works fine though.

Comment: It does work!! Now lets see if I can get this working on my page.

Comment: @JoshMein From my past exp, using `imgParent.childNodes[0].src` is not safe as I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you can use Jquery

```
$('.imageClass').click(function(){
    var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
    $(somewheretoputsrc).attr('src', srcToCopy);
})
```

this code should work

edit : fiddle edited with working image 
http://jsfiddle.net/jbduzan/b7adx/1/

Comment: Would I put this in as an onclick function? because yes I can use jQuery.

Comment: there is several way to do this, add the same class to your images, or create a function that wrap the 2 line inside the click function and call it with a onClick function. I prefer the method that i use on the jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You should go with so called "Unobtrusive JavaScript", i.e. don't mix content with JavaScript and apply the desired behaviors after the window has been loaded.
Something like that:

```
function addDomListener(element, eventName, listener) {
  if (element.addEventListener) // most browsers
    element.addEventListener(eventName, listener, true);
  else if (element.attachEvent) // IE
    element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, listener);
}
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = getElementsByClassName('thumb-link');
  for (int i=0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    var el = elements[i];
    addDomListener(el, "click", function () {
      setImage(el);
    });
  }
}
```

getElementsByClassName still needs an implementation here and every a tag that had onlick previously needs the class 'thumb-link'. But I'm sure you'll figure that out.

Using a library like jQuery or Prototype.js would make it easier here...