# inserting background image to another div

Tags: javascript

I have 4 divs with the same class name and different background images. A hidden div which is displayed when one of four images is clicked. How can I add to my displayed div the background image of the div that is clicked? I do not want to write a function for every image.

```
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.style)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img1.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.style)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img2.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.style)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img3.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.style)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img4.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
 <div class="gallery"></div>
<script>
    function show(){
        var x=document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0];
        x.style.display="block";    
           };
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using any JS framework? JQuery? Prototype?

Comment: Use onclick instead of onClick @ArmineBabertsian

Comment: A new world of event properties would open to you, if you'd use [a proper event attaching method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline handlers.

Comment: Thanx @Teemu , you taught me a new way. Thanks it makes our code less-complexer

Comment: change the function name to show2()
AND one more thing to change the background Image use: x.style.backgroundImage = "url('theImageYouWant.png')"; @ArmineBabertsian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS:

```
 images=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
   var x=document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0];

    for(i=0;i<images.length;i++) {

    images[i].addEventListener("click", function(){  
            src=this.src;

            x.style.display="block";  
       x.style.backgroundImage="url('"+src+"')";}, false);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
 <a href="#"><img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/200x100"></a>
 <a href="#"><img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/300x100"></a>
 <a href="#"><img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/400x100"></a>
 <div class="gallery"></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h7hqfL4d/1/

Answer (score 0):

Need to include the iFrame to show the image in div tag. Find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600828/javascript-get-image-source-and-inject-into-another-image-source)

Comment: You should include the solution here, if you're going to answer a question. As it is, this answer is only a comment. Why an `iframe` is needed for this relatively simple task?